# Direct proof of divisibility

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I need to directly prove, that $$7∣4a→7∣a$$

where $a\in\mathbb Z$.

Since this is a direct proof, we need to assume that $4a$ is divisible by 7, which means that $$4a=7k$$ where k is an integer. From this, we need to arrive at $a=7k$ I've tried several methods, but to me, it seems impossible to refine $4a=7k$ into $a=7k$. Which can be shown if we divide both sides by $4$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $4a=7k$ for some $k$. Use Bézout's identity: we have $1=2\cdot 4- 7$, so, multiplying both sides by $a$, we get
$$a=2\cdot 4a-7a=7(2k-a).$$

Comment: But that only shows that a = 14k - 7a

Comment: It mainly shows $7$ is a factor of $a$. Isn't it what you want to prove?

Comment: Oh I get it now, because 7 ( 2k - a) is the same as 7 times some integer, since 2k - a is an always an integer ( The difference of two integers is an integer )

Comment: Yes. Actually, you can prove Gauß'lemma: if $n$ divides $ab$ and is coprime  with $b$, it divides $a$, exactly the same way , starting from a Bézout's identity between $n$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $7\mid 4a$, then we can write, that $7\mid 21a - 5 \times 4a$, because both $21$ and $4a$ are divisible by $7$, which leads to $7\mid a$.